# Execute several programs at the same time in an initialisation/bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rcs

Hello I am working with a simulator that uses rcS scripts to boot, this is my script

```
cd /tests
./test1 &
./test2 &
./test3 &
./test4 
exit
```

What I want is run all the test at the same time and that the exit command is executed only when all the previous test have finished. And not only when test 4 has finished, is this possible?.
Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to replace "./exit" with just "exit" to exit the shell script.  If you're actually running an executable or script named 'exit' in that directory, I suggest renaming it something less confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use wait:

```
./test1 &
./test2 &
./test3 &
./test4 &
wait
```

From the bash man page:

> wait [n ...]
>                 Wait for  each  specified process and return its
>   termination status.  Each n may be a
>   process ID or a job specification; if
>   a job spec is given, all processes in
>   that job's pipeline are waited for. 
>   If n is not given,
>                 all currently active child processes are waited for, and
>   the return status is zero.  If n
>   specifies a non-existent process or
>   job, the return status is 127. 
>   Otherwise, the return status is the
>   exit status of the  last
>                 process or job waited for.

Comment: Note, if your trying to run a php script, come configurations of php will prevent processes run in the background from outputting anything. I found out that its hard to Google for how to turn on default behaviors. I eventually found this question:  http://serverfault.com/q/564720/210994

Answer (score 5):

`xargs` can support parallel

So just like this:

```
seq 4|xargs -i -n 1 -P 4 ./test{}
```

Comment: Which flag is the one that activates parallel execution? And Do all sub processed start at nearly/exactly the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of

```
cd /tests
./test1 &
./test2 &
./test3 &
./test4 &
wait
exit
```

(I am assuming bash shell)