# multiple jar files in a bash script

Tags: java, bash, jar

So I have a jar file that I need to run five times with a ./run.sh script.

So I put the jar fle back to back in the script 5 times.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar lol.jar
java -jar lol.jar
java -jar lol.jar
java -jar lol.jar
java -jar lol.jar
```

And it didn't work. The java files launch one after the other when I terminate the previous.

So how do I run 5 instances of the same jar at the same time?

I was thinking I could have 5 different .sh scripts and run them all with a 6th one. How do I do that? example please. Thank you!

Comment: Related? [Running a Jar twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10256395/1983854)

Comment: Use something like `java -jar lol.jar & java -jar lol.jar & ...`. See [Execute several programs at the same time in an initialisation/bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430176/execute-several-programs-at-the-same-time-in-an-initialisation-bash-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to run your java processes as **deamons**

You can daemonize any executable in Unix by using nohup and the & operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar lol.jar &
nohup java -jar lol.jar &
nohup java -jar lol.jar &
nohup java -jar lol.jar &
nohup java -jar lol.jar &
```

Comment: there's a problem, like, there are options java jar lol.jar -a dsads -b adsa -c sdasd.
edit: nvm it worked!

Comment: That isn't running anything as a daemon.

Comment: per definition daemon means background process. A & (an ampersand)  at the end of the command means that the process is executed in background

Comment: anyway to add a 5 second delay between each client launch

Comment: add the following line after each java command line: sleep 5

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways:

1. Why don't you write java threaded program.
2. Append '&' at each line as follows. It runs your command in background.

       `java -jar lol.jar &`

   Next you can use following to make comma separated list of Process Ids for further control over running jars.
   `PIDs=${PIDs},$!`
3. Use '&' and loop

       `for i in {0..5}; do java -jar lol.jar & ; done`

Comment: I tried the & but without the nohup only 1 client would launch and not all of them.